# How to calculate $E[X^2]$ for a die roll?

Tags: expected-value, dice

Apparently:

$$
E[X^2] = 1^2 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 2^2 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 3^2\cdot\frac{1}{6}+4^2\cdot\frac{1}{6}+5^2\cdot\frac{1}{6}+6^2\cdot\frac{1}{6}
$$

where $X$ is the result of a die roll.

How come this expansion?

Comment: This is called the second [moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29) of $X$. Does the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_discrete_random_variable.2C_finite_case) help? Have a look at the [Uses and application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Uses_and_applications) section. Particularly, it is useful for calculating the [Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_formula_for_the_variance).

Comment: Kind of. So I would need to evaluate the moment generating function or so? Anyway, then for example evaluating $E[X^3]$ would require some work I guess.

Comment: The expected value for discrete random variables is just the sum of the products of the outcome times its probability...

Answer (score 5):

There are various ways to justify it.

For example, it follows from the definition of expectation and the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Or consider the case $Y=X^2$ and computing $E(Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to compute $E[X^2]$.

If you know how to compute $E[X]$ and $Var(X)$ for a dice roll, then you can work out $E[X^2]$ using [this equivalence of variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition): $Var(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$.

While this is not a general answer (see @Glen_b), this equivalence comes in handy pretty often.